# How to differentiate file or directory created HBase or any other process?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have a requirement where I'm collecting information of all the files or directories created in **HDFS**, Now i want to differentiate files/directory which are created thru **HBase**.

Do we have anything in **HDFS** which can help me to get this information ??

Answer (score 0):

HDFS doesn't provide any such distinction between files created/modified by HBase and other files. But, HBase store all its data into its root directory specified by *hbase.rootdir* property. Its default value is *hdfs://hbase*. I think you can treat every directory/file created inside *hdfs://hbase* as HBase files.

Please comment if you have other points.